# How do I turn a python file, which uses other files, into an executable file?

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, executable

I'm fairly new to python, so I'm still not aware of the proper terminology or the intricacies of this language. Right now, I'm creating a program that is designed to mess with the user (adjust the brightness, change the desktop background, play sounds, etc.) --  completely harmless.

My professor recommended I consider turning the file into an executable. However, the tutorials and information I've researched to do so haven't been very helpful.

The python program I have imports functions from other python files within the same folder. This folder also contains image and sound files that my program uses.

If I were to turn my python file into an executable, I'm assuming I would also have to do something with the other files my program is using, but I'm not sure how to do that, or what to do.

Any help or advice on how to turn my python file into an executable, as well as what to do for the other files my program uses, would be greatly appreciated!

This is all being done on python 3.7 and Windows 10.

Comment: use [PyInstaller](https://pypi.org/project/PyInstaller/).

Comment: @RoadRunner I installed PyInstaller, however, beyond that, I'm not sure what to do. I tried using Powershell, going to the directory where the program is located, and typed "py pyinstaller <filename>.py" But I get an error saying pyinstaller can't be opened because it doesn't exist. Any advice on how to continue?

Comment: Use `pyinstaller <filename>.py`. When you `pip install pyinstaller`, it creates a `pyinstaller.exe` file in your `C:\Python37\Scripts` directory, which can be accessed globally.

Comment: @RoadRunner Thanks for the advice -- I think I almost have it. Within Powershell, I wrote 'C:\ ... \Python37-32\Scripts\pip3 install pyinstaller <filename>.py'. However, I got an error saying it could not find a version that satisfies the requirement '<filename>.py' I'm not very knowledgeable about paths and file locations. However, unless I made some simple mistake with my code above, the python file I'm trying to turn into an executable is located within another folder, completely separate from my python scripts folder. Could that be an issue?